# A python program to keep the first element from a list, and delete the next

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python program which keep the first element from the list, and delete the next.

so like if you have this list:

```
list1=["This","is","test","only"]
```

the program will output:

```
["This","test]
```

Notes:

• The user will fill in the list, so we don't know its length.

Comment: "keep the first element from a list, and delete the next" is not really a good description according to the example. Are you trying to keep every other element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `step` as `2` in [`list slicing`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/):

```
In [71]: list1[::2]
Out[71]: ['This', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

A [slice expression](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) with just a step size of `2` is what you want here:

```
list1=["This","is","test","only"]
list2 = list1[::2]
print(list2)
```

Result:

```
['This', 'test']
```